# React Material Table: edit all rows at once

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have been using https://material-table.com/#/. It works nicely, but for tables where lots of edits are required, it is rather cumbersome to use the row-by-row edit functionality.

What I would like, would be a table-level action that turns the entire table into "edit mode", and a general submit action / cancel action.

This question links to [Material-table editable: Making all rows editable at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58171203/material-table-editable-making-all-rows-editable-at-once) but no satisfactory answer has been provided. I am hoping for better luck.

I do not really know where to start with this, so any help is welcome.

Comment: You can submit a feature request to the collaborators here https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material-table has a bulk update feature that you can use. Below is a sample code from [their websites](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable)

```
<MaterialTable
  editable={{
    onBulkUpdate: (changes) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          // write your logic here
          /* setData([...data, newData]); */
          resolve();
        }, 1000);
      }),
  }}
/>;
```

Comment: I found out later on (or maybe it was added in the mean time, it's quite recent, 1.68.0). But I had to revert to an older version because the latest versions cause various blocking problems

Answer (score 0):

The EditRow functionality given in Material-Table is based on the rowData and not on Table data, similarly yo can override the EditRow, but it limits to rowData and not Table data. As far as I know, material-table doesn't support this feature yet. I suggest you to raise a issue/feature request in their [repo](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table).

However, a possible workaround I can think of is, if the editing column (field) is only one for which you need to edit across the table, then you can override EditRow and provide your own editRow function, in which you need to pass the tableData along with rowData, and onChange you can update the required property for all rows in the tableData.